# OWASP CRS MoD security false positive - rule 942150 "@contains"

Tags: owasp, mod-security

Can someone help with the below,

```
SecRule REQUEST_FILENAME "@streq template.html" \
    "id:9999001,\
    phase:1,\
    pass,\
    t:none,\
    nolog,\
    chain"
    SecRule REQUEST_METHOD "@streq GET" \
        "chain"
        SecRule ARGS:q "@contains cos" \
            "t:none,\
            ctl:ruleRemoveTargetById=942150;ARGS:q"
```

I need to add the another string to @containts as example
"@contains cos, user, name". Please suggest with the right syntax for declaring "contains" with multiple values

Answer (score 0):

`@contains` can't handle multiple words, as it stated in the [documentation](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual-(v2.x)#contains).

You can use `@rx` instead, eg:

```
...
        "chain"
        SecRule ARGS:q "@rx (cos|user|name)" \
            "t:none,\
            ctl:ruleRemoveTargetById=942150;ARGS:q"
```

or you can extend this regular expression as you want, eg. `@rx ^(cos|...)`.